# Excel sheet read only and C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to edit an Excel Sheet through C# code but the Excel sheet is giving me an error saying read only

> CS0200 Property or indexer 'Range.Text' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

This is the code that is trying to access the sheet.
Code:

```
//Load workbook
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"S:\Utils\documents\ServerManager\serverlist.xlsx");
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

xlWorksheet.Range["D2"].Text = "Kelly Cooper";
xlWorksheet.Range["D2"].Style.Font.FontName = "Arial Narrow";
xlWorksheet.Range["D2"].Style.Font.Color = Color.DarkBlue;
```

In the properties the Excel sheet is not read only and when I open it to edit it does not prompt me with the "This document is read only, want to enable editing." How can I go around this, Visual Studio won't let me compile because of it.

This is Excel in Office365.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the document being readonly.  The property you are trying to access is _read only_ at the class/library level.  Most likely you are modifying the value in the wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `.Value` instead of `.Text`.

```
xlWorksheet.Range["D2"].Value = "Kelly Cooper";
xlWorksheet.Range["D2"].Style.Font.FontName = "Arial Narrow";
xlWorksheet.Range["D2"].Style.Font.Color = Color.DarkBlue;
```

If you check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.text.aspx) you can see that Text is **read-only**.

Also, if you check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value.aspx) you can see that Value is **not** read-only.

**EDIT**

You also might have to change your `Open` parameters to:

```
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename: "path/to/file", ReadOnly: false);
```

Comment: This worked but when trying to save, `xlWorkbook.Save()`; I get the same read only error.

Comment: `ReadOnly doesnt exist in the current context`, think I tried this before and had the same error.

Comment: My syntax was wrong, it should be `ReadOnly: false`, and I believe you have to specify `FileName` too

Comment: Still no luck, might just have to move away from excel